# ssh <username>@<localhost> failed on cmd

Tags: linux, ssh, cmd.exe, connection

When I do `ssh -vvv receive:finish_connect`

> - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10061, io:000002CDE9E3A8E0 connect to address localhost port 22: Connection refused

Can anyone tell me how to solve the problem? Thank you.

Comment: I assume you have an ssh server listening on localhost, what did you find on logs ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably an issue with the server not accepting connections over that port. Check [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70357611/using-cmd-to-connect-server-fail) to configure iptables and your ssh config on the server to allow these connections.